# How to exclude the category from the shopping rule in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

i am wanted to apply the discount rule on all the categories in my store except one category . i am going with the following rule.
This rule works fine if i add the product from categories other then 85. but when i add the product with category 85 and also add other category products then rule stop working.
How to achieve this scenario??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this settings, discount rule should apply for all the category except category id 85.

[image]

Comment: If i apply this rule to the category 85 it is still applying ?

Comment: it should exclude the category 85. did you check is it working ?

Comment: I have checked it it does not exclude the category 85. This product is also assigned to other categories. Does this is the reason ?

Comment: I have removed the rule from the condition? and added the rule in the action section

Comment: can i add rules in both sections?

Comment: yes it might be an issue, updated my answer. try with that

Comment: New rule did't work for me . but when i specify the SKU it is working fine, but i have a large number of products.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Not working yet